# Make mongoose request in express post?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to request my MongoDB database using a query obtained from a `<form>` in HTML inside a `post`, it's a bit tricky...

Here is my HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="interface.css" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Bienvenue sur MongoDB !</title>
    </head>

    <body>    
        <form method="post" action="/" id="formulaire">
            <p>
                <label for="rectangle">Nombre de rectangles maximum :</label>
                <input type="range" min="0" max="10" id="rectangle" name="rectangle" />
                <span id="texte1"></span>
            </p>

            <input type="submit" id="envoyer" value="Envoyer" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my Javascript :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/image', function(err) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
});

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.post('/', function (req, res) {    
    var query = Image.find(null);

    query.lte('NbRectangles', req.body.rectangle)

    query.exec(function (err, images) {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }

      for (var i = 0, l = images.length; i < l; i++)
        console.log('Image : ' + images[i]);
    });
});

app.listen(8080);

mongoose.connection.close();
```

This, displays nothing...

My MongoDB collection isn't empty I just removed some code, I did test and when I put the part inside the `post`, outside, It works but what I want is each time I click on the button It displays on the terminal the result of the request.

Thank you in advance...

Comment: Have your checked that req.body.rectangle isn't null?

Comment: Yes I did with : `console.log(req.body.rectangle);`, it works.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like when you receive a request your connection is closed. You should close your connection after executing your query. Also, you should check if your body is not empty and send the response after your request is processed: `res.sendStatus(200)`.

Comment: Even if I remove `mongoose.connection.close();`, it doesn't work.
`mongoose.connection.close();` inside `post` give me `MongoError: Topology was destroyed`.

Comment: You need to wait until all db calls are completed before closing your connection. You can try connecting during your application start up and disconnect during shutdown. Did you `require` your Image model? Have you tried parsing `rectangle` to number? Try adding named logs instead of throwing errors, it's easier to debug, for instance: `if (err) {
        console.error('exec callback: ', err); return;
      }`